# Transactions dependency between rest services

Tags: web-services, rest, transactions

We are converting our application to support SOA, mainly into restful services. I have the services developed, however I am now concerned about how to rollback the transaction of service 1 if service 2 fails.

I have a page made of three services. If any of the service fails then i have to roll back the entire page to the previous state and make sure all the asynchronous service calls fired from the page are rolled back as well.

I don't have any direction how to handle this. Can anyone throw light on this.

Let me know if i am not making sense and have to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: use compensation actions and idempotence

In more detail:

SOA and REST are architectural styles. This also means that when moving from a monolith to SOA and moving from distributed transactions to REST as well as moving from RPC (RMI, etc.) to REST, you have to rethink transactions.

Lets first have a look how this works in the non-REST world and then how this changes. You are a bit vague on how your current application looks like so I'll point out a range of scenarios.

### Monolith

When you have a monolithic application, your whole code resides in the same artifact, all processing is done on the same machine, and all data access is centralized. You can have a single transaction that spans everything. Your DBMS grants you the [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

### Distributed Transactions

There are ways to span a transaction across the network and coordinate several nodes using [2PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). This is not very different from the monolith scenario -- except there are more latencies, more rollbacks, more scaling issues, etc.

### SOA

In a SOA world, you stop coupling your services using the database and have your services interact using service interfaces instead. This has plenty of advantages but also some consequences, you should be aware of.

In SOA you don't use distributed transactions but every service has its own database and its own transaction. When there are two services and service A calls service B and B fails, A can recognize this failure (catch the exception or let the container handle that) and rollback its own transaction. But if A has successfully called B and then fails before committing its own transaction than there is no possibility what so ever to rollback the transaction at B because at B the transaction is already committed. In short: You don't have ACID anymore with SOA. There is no guarantee on atomicity or consistency and only partial isolation. Get used to it.

In fact ACID is a lie for normal RDBMS, too. When they are operated on pure ACID compliance ("serializable") they get unusably slow. Because of that, DBMS have different [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) where you allow them to make certain shortcuts. Actually almost nobody operates a database such that they really guarantee ACID. The inconsistencies that may occur are just rare enough so you can tolerate them. Inconsistencies can occur and you have to recover from them or work around them.

The same thing applies when you handle with something outside your database. You cannot unprint an invoice. You cannot unsend an email, etc. You cannot unbake a cake. You have to find a suitable compensation action.

And this is also what you have to do in a SOA environment. Inconsistencies may occur and this means you have to handle them for yourself. There are several ways to do so:

- If they are rare enough and the data is not that critical, you may safely ignore them.
- If they are rare enough, you can choose to handle them manually. If there's a problem with one customer per year, fix the problem when the customer complains, apologize, and send him a goody or so.
- If these problems occur more often than you can handle manually, implement an automatic compensation action. If the invoice is printed, throw it a way. If you already sent it, send a cancellation. If the customer has already payed, send a credit note, etc.

  You are already used to having compensation actions in your application. You can handle failing service just like a wrong invoice. And just like in the wrong invoice example, it heavily depends on the concrete failure situation how you may want to handle it. Maybe the correct solution is to delete some database record. Or you need to repeat a service call. Or you need to make another service call. I cannot tell you what exactly you need to do but you will know it when you think about it.

### REST

One thing which can go wrong and may need a compensation action is that a service call can fail (for several reasons). REST and HTTP have several mechanisms which help you in this case.

One of these mechanisms is [idempotence](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/idempotency.html). If your service call failed or if you are not sure if it succeeded, you can just retry the service call. You are required to make all your GET, PUT, and DELETE operations idempotent so your service clients can safely retry. POST and PATCH operations are not required to be idempotent, although especially with PATCH it is helpful if they are so nevertheless.

There are quite sophisticated mechanisms (e.g. calls with preconditions) but in fact with idempotence you can handle 95% of your problems. You can read about them when you are used to rest. At the beginning you should stick to the basics. Only use the more sophisticated stuff if you have a good reason to do so.

BTW: It is very helpful to have a unit test which checks for idempotence. Especially if you are not used to it or if there is some complicated stuff going on, it is advisable to check this as you really don't want to get that wrong.

### Conclusion

The solution is not to bring transactions to SOA and REST but to think in a service-oriented and restful way when you develop your application.